# ublock, adblock: block elements with dynamical id

Tags: filter, block, rules, adblock

Bottom of page [imperiyanews](http://www.imperiyanews.ru/details/f95717b7-46b8-e811-80f5-020c5d00406e)

Where is div and table with dinamical id

Them look like `<div id="ZzRwXzE3NzMwXzE1MzY5NDQ0MDA" data-ids="1587700,1586609,1586068,1587550,1587700,1586609,1587550,1586068,1586068,1588089,1588041,1587131"><table id="ZzRwXzE3NzMwXzE1MzY5NDQ0MDA_table_17730"`

I tried to filter them out by rules like

```
www.imperiyanews.ru##table[id$="A_table_17730"]
www.imperiyanews.ru##[class^="Z"]
www.imperiyanews.ru##[id^="Z"]
www.imperiyanews.ru##.b-block.block > div > div:nth-of-type(3)
```

But rules didnt work for me.
In element picker mode - these rules hilighted right element, but after reload page - element not filtered